# Shopify checkout dynamic generated html class?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm reaching the checkout for getting the final price to pay :

```
  let checkout = await fetch("/checkout/");
   checkout = await checkout.text();
   let total_price = checkout.match(
            /<dl class="order-summary-toggle(.*?)<\/dl>/gim
          );
```

The problem is i noticed on some store checkout page got dynamic generated class, and i dont know why and cant reproduce?

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3aJk.png)

Is someone know why is it happening ? or if there is an better way to get the checkout final price ?

Answer (score 0):

The html will not be complete because is dynimically created with Javascript.

If you are using liquid the total price can be accessed with `{{cart.total_price}}`.

If not, and you want to use the [cartjs api](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#get-locale-cart-js)  you can call `/cart.js` and use the field  "total_price"

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Your total is: "+data.total_price);
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```